# Can't sudo unless I su as another user and then su back to my account?

Tags: sudo, su

```
user@greeneyes:~$ sudo apt-get install xdotool
user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
user@greeneyes:~$ su verelse
Password: 
verelse@greeneyes:/home/user$ su user
Password: 
user@greeneyes:~$ sudo apt-get install xdotool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libxdo3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxdo3 xdotool
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 61.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 204 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libxdo3 amd64 1:3.20160805.1-3 [20.5 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 xdotool amd64 1:3.20160805.1-3 [41.0 kB]
Fetched 61.5 kB in 0s (136 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package libxdo3:amd64.
(Reading database ... 168281 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxdo3_1%3a3.20160805.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxdo3:amd64 (1:3.20160805.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xdotool.
Preparing to unpack .../xdotool_1%3a3.20160805.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xdotool (1:3.20160805.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up libxdo3:amd64 (1:3.20160805.1-3) ...
Setting up xdotool (1:3.20160805.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

this is odd

```
user@greeneyes:~$ whoami
user
user@greeneyes:~$ sudo su
user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
user@greeneyes:~$ su user
Password: 
user@greeneyes:~$ whoami
user
user@greeneyes:~$ sudo su
root@greeneyes:/home/user#
```

Comment: Did you add yourself to the `sudo` group recently? And did not log out and log in?

Comment: @muru I logged out back to the initial login page and then log back in. It did not occur to me to completely restart the server. I have since done so and that solves it. Thank you. Now I feel stupid LOL

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title, that's not how this site works. instead post an answer below, it's completely fine to answer your own question. You'll be able to "accept" the answer after 2 days to correctly indicate the issue is resolved.

Comment: @pomsky muru provided the answer. So I have to wait two days to mark his answer as accepted? That's kind of weird. I guess I'll come back in 2 days

Comment: You can accept answer by **others** immediately (well, at least 15 minutes after the question is posted). You only have to wait for two days if you want accept the answer you have posted.